# Create a payment via the Windows Store in Windows Universal Apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, payment-gateway, win-universal-app

Is possible to create a payment via Windows Store when purchased content is a HTML content downloaded from cloud in Windows Universal Apps? I was only able to find, that Window Store provides:

- Time trial
- In-app purchases (this is close, but with in-app purchases all content must be part of application and I'm using downloadable HTML content from cloud, which isn't part of application)
- Ads

So, I'm basically talking about situation, when Windows Store works like Payment system (like PayPal)... Or can you give me any advice how to handle this type of purchases across platforms (iOS, Android, Kindle, ...)?